# UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')

Tags: python, numpy, dataset

I tried to run this function and got an error as mentioned below the coding. Please help me to solve it.

```py
outliers = []                                                                             
def detect_out(data):                           
    threshold = 3
    mean = np.mean(data)
    std = np.std(data)
    
    for i in data:
        z_score = (i - mean)/std
        if np.abs(z_score) > threshold:
            outliers.append(i)
    return(outliers)
```

This is the function I created to detect outliers in my dataset. When I tried to call this function as mentioned below:

```py
outlr = detect_out(num_data)   
outlr
```

I'm getting the error:

> UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')

What should I do now?

Comment: Could you give which line in the function that is causing the error? Is the data argument a string?

Comment: You are trying subtract strings, 'U32'